# How do I join 2 tables using substring of one column

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables Table A has a list of servers and Table B is a dump of filenames in a directory.
Example of Table A

```
ID Server
1 Development.Stage
2 Development.DEV
3 Development.QA
4 Production
5 APPS
```

etc...

Example of Table B

```
FileName
Development.Stage.V01B01.ConferenceApp.Bruce.20170106
Development.Stage.V01B02.ConferenceApp.Michael.20170612
Development.DEV.V01B01.AdvantageUpgrade.Bruce.20171121
Development.DEV.V01B02.AdvantageUpgrade.Bruce.20180102
Development.QA.V02B01.AdvantageUpgrade.Bruce.20180306
Development.QA.V02B02.AdvantageUpgrade.Bruce.20180415
Development.QA.V02B03.AdvantageUpgrade.Bruce.20180511
Production.V03B01.AdvantageUpgrade.Bruce.20180410
Production.V03B02.AdvantageUpgrade.Bruce.20180503
Development.Stage.V01B01.AnnualMeeting.Bruce.20160724
Development.Stage.V01B03.AnnualMeeting.Shane.20170719
```

etc...

I'd like to be able to join Table A to Table B using the substring of Table B that matches the Server column on Table A.

Comment: From first position, or anywhere?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: See updated answer below - should work

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select * from tableA a join tableB b on b.filename like '%'+a.server+'%'
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Select  *
    FROM TableA as a
    JOIN TableB as b 
on b.FileName like a.Server+'%'
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: this is ascii standard sql format, will work with mysql and tsql

Comment: You mean ANSI SQL, but it's not ANSI SQL compliant. Will however work with tsql, and _maybe_ MySQL too.

Answer (score 0):

The ANSI standard solution looks like:

```
select . . .
from a join
     b
     on b.filename = a.server || '%';
```

Note that this is likely to be inefficient in most databases.

EDIT:

SQL Server uses `+` instead of `||`:

```
select . . .
from a join
     b
     on b.filename = a.server + '%';
```

Comment: The second query is the ANSI SQL one, since ANSI SQL specifies `||` for concatenation, not the `concat()` function.

Comment: @jarlh . .  I think it supports both, but I can't check right now.

Comment: I've searched the SQL-2016 spec (just in case), and `concat` was not found. (`<concatenation operator> ::= ||`)

Comment: SQL-2016 as in ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016(E), i.e. the current version of the ISO/ANSI SQL standard.

Comment: @jarlh . . . Sorry about that.  I'm not sure where I got the idea that `concat()` is in the standard.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id, a.server, b.filename
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b ON (a.server = SUBSTRING_INDEX(b.filename, '.', 2));
```

This should work for MySQL DBMS.